Get SwiftUI preview to work with NavigationStack
I've abstracted my navigation into a service for my SwiftUI app. When I run it on the simulator or physical device it works perfectly. However, when testing in the #Preview, the navigation doesn't seem to work.
I understand there are some limitations, but is there a way I could potentially create a Swift NavigationStack preview wrapper (for only in #Preview) so that if I wanted to test certain screens I could also test the navigation?
At the moment I can only preview one screen at a time, but have to keep a simulator running for navigation flow. For proper testing that's okay, but when building or testing a UI flow I like the preview.
I'm currently running Xcode 15.4.0.
This is some bare minimum code to demonstrate:
protocol NavigationRouteRepresentable: Hashable {
    associatedtype Body: View
    @ViewBuilder @MainActor var body: Self.Body { get }
}

enum Route: NavigationRouteRepresentable {
    case settings

    var body: some View {
        switch self {
            case .settings:
                Text("Settings")
        }
    }
}

final class RouteManager<Route: NavigationRouteRepresentable>: ObservableObject {
    @Published var routes: NavigationPath
    init() { self.routes = NavigationPath() }
    func push(to screen: Route) { routes.append(screen) }
}

struct NavigationWrapper: View {
    @StateObject
    private var routeManager: RouteManager<Route> = .init()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $routeManager.routes) {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(routeManager)
        }
        .navigationDestination(for: Route.self) { destination in
            destination.body
                .environmentObject(routeManager)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject
    private var routeManager: RouteManager<Route>

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello World")
            .toolbar {
                Button("Go") {
                    routeManager.push(to: .settings)
                }
            }
    }
}

#Preview {
    @StateObject var routeManager: RouteManager<Route> = .init()
    return NavigationStack(path: $routeManager.routes) {
        ContentView()
            .environmentObject(routeManager)
    }
}


If you use return NavigationWrapper() in the #previewworks fine for me
